# Does Deleting a Campaign Cascade Delete Campaign Members?

Tags: campaign

Does deleting a Campaign cascade delete Campaign Members?

CampaignMemeber sObject documentation says "yes" (CampaignId required):
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm

Sales Objects Data Model:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

Comment: I would believe so yes. Are you observing different behavior?

Comment: @Eric Not at all, behavior supports it. Want to get an official answer from the Community before I run the rest of my purging scripts.

Comment: Then I would say YES. If the CampaignId is required then the record cannot exist without it. So it would have to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever want to know whether the child members are cascade deleted, a metadata browsing tool will tell (like Workbench). It is also queryable via the describe methods within Apex.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Campaign Members cannot exist without either the Campaign and the Lead or Contact (this is a many-to-many master-detail relationship). They will be cascade deleted, meaning that they will not appear in the Recycle Bin, and will be restored if the original record(s) is/are recovered from the Recycle Bin.